# What vector does the electrostatic field assign to a point?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, definition, vector-fields

I know that the electrostatic field is a vector field. The definition of a vector field is that it is a function which assigns a vector to each point in space. So my question is: what vector does the electric field assign to each point? Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but the book I am using has been extremely unclear about this.

Comment: Yeah i realised my title was misleading. Edited it.

Comment: I am confused by what you are asking. The vector the electric field assigns to a point is... the electric field vector.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field can be used like a sensor. Usually we have to ask the electric field function for an answer, say what is the electric field at this particular point [3,1]?

Then it will give us an answer as an arrow vector of some length. This arrow is the direction that a positive charge will follow if we let it go at this particular point. The length is how fast this positive charge will start to move move once we let it go.

Whether the field is "real" or not permeating all space is of some debate, I think, usually we can just think of the electric field as an arrow sign symbolizing what a positive charge will do if we release it at that particular place...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ in $\text{V}\,\text{m}^{-1}$. It is the force field of a test charge.

Answer (score 0):

Field is an imaginary region in space in which evry point is affected by force. This applies to all field forces like gravity, eletrical, magnetic etc. It is a vector quantity

Coming to your eletrostatic field, its a type of field present which affects only particles having property of **electrical charge**. That is, that any partcile which possess such property of electrical charge, when placed in an electric field, experiences force. Thus, we write:

$$\vec F_{\text{electric}}=q\vec E$$

Electric field can also be written in **electric potential** terms:
$$\vec E=-\frac{dV}{d\vec r}$$

Now electric field is generated by particles possessing charge. Note that in reality, there is no significance of 'electric field lines' as depicted. They are imaginary.

[image]